# Drop Filepath on DIR

Tags: ruby

I am having problems splitting the filepath and just getting the filenames.

Here is my Code:

```
file=File.new("files.txt", "w")
file_list=Dir["../path/*txt"]

file.puts file_list
```

I tried a few different ways to split it, but I keep getting an Array Error,

Best Regards,

AZCards

Comment: What contents of 'files.txt' do you want? Should it be contents of all specified files ('*.txt' in your case) merged into one big resulted file?

Comment: Files.txt would contain a list of files in that directory that have the ending of .txt, really I just need the filenames of those files, no txt no path.

Comment: When/how do you get "Array Error"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this snippet:

```
file = File.new("files.txt", "w")
Dir['../path/*.txt'].each { |f| file.puts File.basename(f, '.txt') }
```

That give you a list of filenames in specified folder without 'txt' extension.

Answer (score 0):

```
file=File.new("files.txt", "w")
Dir.entries("/path/to/directory").each do |path|
   m = /([^\/]+)\.txt$/.match(path)
   file.puts m[1] if m
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Just map the list of full paths, using [basename](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/File.html#method-c-basename), yielding the bare filename list.
Assuming you can want to drop extensions:

```
file = File.new("files.txt", "w")
file_list = Dir["../path/*txt"].map {|f| File.basename f, '.txt'}

file.puts file_list
```

Comment: This also worked, but it kept the file extension so I used WarHog instead.  Thanks though!

Comment: Which Ruby are you using? MRI doesn't keep the file extension, in fact the File.basename call is the same as WarHog's solution.